# Grouping objects by multiple columns with Lodash or Underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have following object `records`:

```
 {  
   "notes":[  
      {  
         "id":1,
         "description":"hey",
         "userId":2,
         "replyToId":null,
         "postId":2,
         "parentId":null
      },
      {  
         "id":5,
         "description":"hey test",
         "userId":3,
         "replyToId":null,
         "postId":2,
         "parentId":null
      },
      {  
         "id":2,
         "description":"how are you",
         "userId":null,
         "replyToId":2,
         "postId":2,
         "parentId":null,
         "user":null
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to output it as:

```
2 
  object with id 1
  object with id 2 (because replyToId value is same as userId
3
  object with id 5
```

So basically I want to consider UserId and replyToId value under the same group.

I have build my own mixin under lodash, wrapping groupBy method as:

```
mixin({
    splitGroupBy: function(list, groupByIter){
        if (_.isArray(groupByIter)) {
            function groupBy(obj) {
                return _.forEach(groupByIter, function (key){
                    if ( !!obj[key] ) return obj[key]
                });

            }
        } else {
            var groupBy = groupByIter;
        }

        debugger;

        var groups = _.groupBy(list, groupBy);

        return groups;
    }
});
```

Call looks like this:

```
_.splitGroupBy(data.notes,['userId', 'replyToId']);
```

The output is coming without group. Even when I have tried with `_.map` instead `_.forEach` the split is not happening correctly.

Comment: Can you redo the "JSON" portion of your question?

Comment: As a note: [MDN: Conditionally defining a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Conditionally_defining_a_function): While `[...]functions can be conditionally defined [...]` (since ES3) they are `[...]no longer allowed in ES5 strict. Additionally, this feature does not work consistently cross-browser, so you should not rely on it.[...]`

Comment: @AdrianLynch It has been updated now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A solution using underscore:

```
    var props = ['userId', 'replyToId'];

    var notNull = _.negate(_.isNull);

    var groups = _.groupBy(record.notes, function(note){
        return _.find(_.pick(note, props), notNull);
    });
```

Comment: let me check later evening and will confirm you the result.

Comment: Any reason for the down vote on the 26 June 2020? Let me know what's wrong so that I can fix it. Nobody learns from anonymous down votes.

Answer (score 3):

This can probably done much prettier, but it should work:

```
lodash.mixin({
  splitGroupBy: function(list, groupByIter) {
    var _ = this, groupBy;
    if (lodash.isArray(groupByIter)) {
      groupBy = function(obj) {
        return _(obj) .pick(groupByIter)
                      .values()
                      .without(null, undefined)
                      .first();
      };
    } else {
      groupBy = groupByIter;
    }
    var groups = _.groupBy(list, groupBy);
    return groups;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use stringify object as key.

```
_.groupBy(notes, ({ userId, replyToId }) => JSON.stringify({ userId, replyToId }));
```

output:

```
{
  "{\"userId\":2,\"replyToId\":null}": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "description": "hey",
      "userId": 2,
      "replyToId": null,
      "postId": 2,
      "parentId": null
    }
  ],
  "{\"userId\":3,\"replyToId\":null}": [
    {
      "id": 5,
      "description": "hey test",
      "userId": 3,
      "replyToId": null,
      "postId": 2,
      "parentId": null
    }
  ],
  "{\"userId\":null,\"replyToId\":2}": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "description": "how are you",
      "userId": null,
      "replyToId": 2,
      "postId": 2,
      "parentId": null,
      "user": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could map your list of attributes to their respective values and pick the first non falsy value as your group key:

```
_.mixin({
    splitGroupBy: function(list, groupByIter){
        if (!_.isArray(groupByIter))
            return _.groupBy(list, groupByIter);

        return _.groupBy(list, function(o) {
            var values = _.map(groupByIter, function(k) {
                return o[k];
            });
            return _.find(values);
        });
    }
});
```

```js
var data = {  
   "notes":[  
      {  
         "id":1,
         "userId":2,
         "replyToId":null
      },
      {  
         "id":5,
         "userId":3,
         "replyToId":null
      },
      {  
         "id":2,
         "userId":null,
         "replyToId":2
      }
   ]
};

_.mixin({
    splitGroupBy: function(list, groupByIter){
        if (!_.isArray(groupByIter))
            return _.groupBy(list, groupByIter);

        return _.groupBy(list, function(o) {
            var values = _.map(groupByIter, function(k) {
                return o[k];
            });
            return _.find(values);
        });
    }
});

snippet.log(JSON.stringify(_.splitGroupBy(data.notes,['userId', 'replyToId'])));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>

<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great comment! This did exactly what i wanted! Great example too

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `userId` and `replyToId` are mutually exclusive (i.e. you either have a `userId` or a `replyToId`, but never both) as they are in the sample data, then specifying a custom grouping function works:

```
_.groupBy(data.notes, function(note) {
    return note.userId || note.replyToId;
});
```