# get grouped by array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, underscore.js

I have a JSON file and I would like this JSON to be grouped by according to three fields in it.

The JSON looks as follow(with more items of course):

```
{
  "Racename": "10KM",
  "Category": 34,
  "Gender": "Male",
  "Work": "Google",
  "FullName": "Dave Happner",
  "Rank": 1,
  "Ponit": 1,
  "Numparticipant": 0,
  "rankparticipant": 0,
  "precentagePart": "0",
  "NumRaces": 1,
  "RaceTime": "2018-10-18T00:34:20",
  "rankCat": 1,
  "PointCat": 1,
  "RaceDate": "2018-10-05"
}
```

The requested result (using `underscore` or `lodash`) is:

```js
 [
   {
     "Racename" : "10KM",
     "Category": "34",
     "Gender": "Male",
     runner : [
     {
      "Work": "Google",
      "FullName": "Dave Happner",
      "Rank": 1,
      "Ponit": 1,
      "Numparticipant": 0,
      "rankparticipant": 0,
      "precentagePart": "0",
      "NumRaces": 1,
      "RaceTime": "2018-10-18T00:34:20",
      "rankCat": 1,
      "PointCat": 1,
      "RaceDate": "2018-10-05"
     }]
```

Comment: I am a newbie, so I'm not sure what or how the object should look like.
I do know I need it as a new array\list or a new JSON file , just grouped by. at the end of the day I need to iterate the JSON and show a HTML blocks which will be according to the grouped items.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/29587488/

Comment: ok let me try and edit my post

Comment: @CertainPerformance hope it's clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `reduce` into an object indexed by a string, made up of the `Racename`, `Category`, and `Gender`, joined by a character that won't be present in the values, such as `_`. For example, your input in the question would result in an object with a key of `10KM_34_Male`. On every iteration, check to see if the constructed key exists - if it doesn't, create the object, with an empty `runner` array. Then, push to the `runner` array.

After you've finished with the `reduce`, you can get the object's values to get your desired array output:

```js
const input = [{
  "Racename": "10KM",
  "Category": 34,
  "Gender": "Male",
  "Work": "Google",
  "FullName": "Dave Happner",
  "Rank": 1,
  "Ponit": 1,
  "Numparticipant": 0,
  "rankparticipant": 0,
  "precentagePart": "0",
  "NumRaces": 1,
  "RaceTime": "2018-10-18T00:34:20",
  "rankCat": 1,
  "PointCat": 1,
  "RaceDate": "2018-10-05"
}];

const outputObj = input.reduce((a, { Racename, Category, Gender, ...rest }) => {
  const key = [Racename, Category, Gender].join('_');
  if (!a[key]) {
    a[key] = { Racename, Category, Gender, runner: [] };
  }
  a[key].runner.push(rest);
  return a;
}, {});
const output = Object.values(outputObj);
console.log(output);
```

Or, using a larger input:

```js
const input = [{
  "Racename": "10KM",
  "Category": 34,
  "Gender": "Male",
  "Work": "Google",
  "FullName": "Dave Happner",
  "Rank": 1,
  "Ponit": 1,
  "Numparticipant": 0,
  "rankparticipant": 0,
  "precentagePart": "0",
  "NumRaces": 1,
  "RaceTime": "2018-10-18T00:34:20",
  "rankCat": 1,
  "PointCat": 1,
  "RaceDate": "2018-10-05"
},{
  "Racename": "10KM",
  "Category": 34,
  "Gender": "Male",
  "Work": "Amazon",
  "FullName": "Bob Joe",
  "Rank": 12,
  "Ponit": 2,
  "Numparticipant": 0,
  "rankparticipant": 0,
  "precentagePart": "0",
  "NumRaces": 1,
  "RaceTime": "2018-10-18T00:34:20",
  "rankCat": 1,
  "PointCat": 1,
  "RaceDate": "2018-10-05"
},{
  "Racename": "20KM",
  "Category": 40,
  "Gender": "Male",
  "Work": "Google",
  "FullName": "Dave Happner",
  "Rank": 1,
  "Ponit": 1,
  "Numparticipant": 0,
  "rankparticipant": 0,
  "precentagePart": "0",
  "NumRaces": 1,
  "RaceTime": "2018-10-18T00:34:20",
  "rankCat": 1,
  "PointCat": 1,
  "RaceDate": "2018-10-05"
}
];

const outputObj = input.reduce((a, { Racename, Category, Gender, ...rest }) => {
  const key = [Racename, Category, Gender].join('_');
  if (!a[key]) {
    a[key] = { Racename, Category, Gender, runner: [] };
  }
  a[key].runner.push(rest);
  return a;
}, {});
const output = Object.values(outputObj);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: not sure if I can ask questions on an answered question, but I'll try anyway . the `output` is an `array` type? I would like to use the returned object but not sure how do I find of which type is it. cheers

Comment: Yes, `output` is an array - have to transform the `outputObj`, which is an object, not an array, into the `output` array. You can check `Array.isArray(arg)` to see if `arg` is an array or not.

Comment: it is an array according to your suggested `Array.isarray(arg)`, but when using `console.log(arg[0])` I'm getting `[object object]` while I'm expecting to have the first array's value. no? thanks again

Comment: It's an array of objects, so `output[0]` will reference an object. If you wanted to get just the values from that, call `Object.values` on it. `Object.values(output[0])` to get `[
  "10KM",
  34,
  "Male",
  [
    {
      "Work": "Google",
      "FullName": "Dave Happner", ...`

Comment: perfect ! Thanks again !! I think it's the last thing in order to complete my understanding and puzzle. When I log it, I do get something similar but with `object `items : `[ "10KM", 34, "Male", [ { "[object object],[object object], [object object] ...`

Comment: Those `"[object Object]"`s aren't in the code above, as you can see from the snippet - sounds like something you're doing is stringifying them for some reason. If you want key-value pairs without unhelpful stringifying, you can use `JSON.stringify` on the array (or on any object)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186299/discussion-between-yaniv-eliav-and-certainperformance).